# Extract form data from interactive form pdf

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to create a pdf file that have some input fields like text, drop down, check box, radio fields etc. The fields are editable i.e I can put values on the fields.My pdf is looking as follows :
[image]

Now I want to extract the values from the fields and update database.

Comment: If picture above shows dump from pdf, what does it has to do with PHP?

Comment: why use pdf and not a regular html `form` if you need to extract the values of fields? you could just use regular html then generate a pdf after processing.